# mysql bash command fail in moba extreme but n cmd windows success

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface, mobaxterm

I can't run a mysql command in mobaxterm, but when I try the same command in a cmd prompt, it works. Commands such as mysql -V, mysql -U admin -P, etc. What's wrong with mobaxterm?

It return: bash: mysql: command not found

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't have mysql in your path in the MobaXterm shell.

Under the settings menu, go to configuration. In the terminal tab, the checkbox next to `Use Windows PATH environment` should be checked.

Comment: After I set checkbox the usew windows path environment option, and try a simple code such as mysql -uroot in new tab, the process is no responded or no result appear. What is the next problem?

Comment: @mhanif That's a separate question. I don't know mysql.

Comment: don't it related to mobaxtreme ?

Comment: No, mysql is a database.

Comment: I know that, but why command for mysql is working at windows cmd but not in mobaxterm although I've checklist the checkbox of use windows path environment in mobaxterm?